# find and replace lines of data in h2o flow

Tags: h2o

I am wondering how to find and replace certain values of data in H2O flow.  For example, if a line of data is '0.003 8.938 0.005 9.999' I would like to find all of the '9.999' and replace with NaN, so sort of like sed?
Is there a way to do this directly in the Flow interface?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point in time, Flow is primarily a modeling tool and not a data munging tool, so there is not currently a way to do this.  Sed is an efficient tool for find/replace, so that's what I'd recommend.  Once you edit the file, you should import the file into the H2O cluster for modeling.  Or you can do more advanced munging on the data as an H2OFrame using the R or Python API for H2O.